# While loop condition for displaying images

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display all seats of a airline. If the seat is taken the image will be a red circle if it is vacant it will be green. what is the shorter way of doing this?

**Sample Code**

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select *  from flight_seat_status where flight_number = '$_SESSION[departure]'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
     if (seat['status'] == 'vacant'){ <img src = "green.png"...>}else { img src = "red.png"...>
```

another thing i want to do is put them in rows of 4 using a tables in html

Comment: Show us your `$seats` array.

Comment: what do you mean by $seats array.

Comment: Why you use `while($seat)`?

Comment: You can use ternary operator https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples

Comment: use ```print_r($seat);``` & share us the output.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [PHP Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to echo the image:

```
echo "<img src='" . ($seat['status'] == 'vacant') ? "green.png" : "red.png" . "'>"
```

Comment: In PHP it should be `$seat['status']` instead of `seat['status']`.